# newbie android programming compile error

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to compile and run the OpenGL example code here:

http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html

I imported the project into Eclipse, but when trying to compile, I get this and other similar errors.

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The method onSurfaceCreated(GL10, EGLConfig) of type MyGLRenderer must override a superclass 
 method
- implements android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer.onSurfaceCreated
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks
Bob

Answer (score 2):

This stems from the `@Override` annotation.  Make sure your compiler is set for Java 1.6. Assuming you're correctly implementing the method signature, the compiler compliance could be an issue.  Regardless you can remove the annotation, but if you're not implementing the signature correctly it won't be called as expected.

Comment: Well like I say I can't try it on my device.  I tried it on a Virtual machine, but it quit as soon as it started running.  I'm not sure if it quit because of this problem though.  This code is not mine, it is sample code I downloaded straight from the Android site.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your java compiler is set to 1.5. Go to project preferences and check compiler. If this is the case, change it to 1.6 and it should take care of the problem. If that doesn't work, post the code you have for that method and we will see.

Comment: it is set to 1.6 already.  I was able to get rid of the errors simply by removing the @Override statement -- should that be OK?  Although now I can't test it because it says the app requires Android version 14 and my device is 10!

Comment: As long as you are passing and accepting the correct amount/type of variables you should be good. That was going to be my next suggestion. You can change the android target version in the manifest. Although, I don't know if that program requires API 14 because I haven't dealt with it. This link explains more about the API's http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: Also, you can set up a virtual device to test on with the appropriate Android version. Isn't as nice as using actual hardware but it works

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the compiler settings for the project ITSELF - not just by going to "Preferences - Compiler".

Right click on your project, choose project properties, and change the compiler compliance level to 1.6 from there.

I know this is an old question, but since many people may have this issue I wanted to post a more accurate solution.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative reason why you may be running into this error -- make sure you're using the correct import for the class `EGLConfig` -- Android Studio gave me two choices for the library I wanted, `javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig` or `android.opengl.EGLConfig`. I picked the second, which lead to this error. Picking the first fixed it.

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553920/implementing-glsurfaceview-renderer-issues)