# Implementing GLSurfaceView.Renderer Issues

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

## Code derived from the tutorial

I am beginning some **OpenGL-ES 2.0** for the Android system.  I took the following code from: http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html#renderer

```
public class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }
}
```

### I am receiving the following error

> Gradle: error: MyRenderer is not abstract and does not override abstract method onSurfaceCreated(GL10,EGLConfig) in Renderer

Does anyone know how to proceed?  I need to use the `MyRenderer` class to pass to the `GLSurfaceView`, so simply declaring it abstract is not a viable solution.  Can anybody shed some light on my problem?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

## Found the Issue!

The **Incorrect** version of the imports looked like this

```
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.EGLConfig;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
```

But `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` wanted the `EGLConfig` from the `javax` library

The following code is the **Correct** version of the imports

```
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
```

---

## I discovered this after looking at the interface implementation

```
public static interface Renderer {
    void onSurfaceCreated(javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10 gl10, javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig eglConfig);

    void onSurfaceChanged(javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10 gl10, int i, int i1);

    void onDrawFrame(javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10 gl10);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I really wish their documentation would include the imports.  This has burned me many times.  So annoying.